# function that adds extra lines to itself by the input number

Tags: r, function, lapply

I want to write a function for the below codes to avoid repeating them in a long format code. As an example these are my codes:

```
l = nrow(p)
for (i in 1:l) {
      node<- apply(p[c((i + 1) : l), ], 1, function(x){
        a = c(as.character(p[i,1]) , as.character(x[1]))

        cond1 = ifelse(nrow(Network1[((Network1$from == a[1]) & (Network1$to) == a[2]), ]) != 0 |
                         nrow(Network1[((Network1$from == a[2]) & (Network1$to) == a[1]), ]) != 0, TRUE, FALSE)

        if (((cond1   == 1) & (zsd== 1)) {
          return(c(as.character(p[i, 5]), as.character(x[5])))
        }

        if ((zsd== FALSE)) {
          t1 = as.character(p[i, 1]) == as.character(x[1])
          mycond = cond1  
          TT = t1  
          if (TT + mycond >= z){
            return(c(as.character(p[i, 2]), as.character(x[2])))
          }

        }
      })
```

In this codes have been written for 1:2 numbers. However, I like to make gather them in function in which by what number the input is, it generates the lines for more numbers, like below that code is changed for 1:2 as inputs:

```
l = nrow(p)
for (i in 1:l) {
      node<- apply(p[c((i + 1) : l), ], 1, function(x){
        a = c(as.character(p[i,1]) , as.character(x[1]))
        b = c(as.character(p[i,2]) , as.character(x[2]))

        cond1 = ifelse(nrow(Network1[((Network1$from == a[1]) & (Network1$to) == a[2]), ]) != 0 |
                         nrow(Network1[((Network1$from == a[2]) & (Network1$to) == a[1]), ]) != 0, TRUE, FALSE)
        cond2 = ifelse(nrow(Network2[((Network2$from == b[1]) & (Network2$to) == b[2]), ]) != 0 |
                         nrow(Network2[((Network2$from == b[2]) & (Network2$to) == b[1]), ]) != 0, TRUE, FALSE)

        if (((cond1 + cond2  == 1) & (zsd== 1)) |
            ((cond1 + cond2  == 2) & (zsd== 2)) {
          return(c(as.character(p[i, 5]), as.character(x[5])))
        }

        if ((zsd== FALSE)) {
          t1 = as.character(p[i, 1]) == as.character(x[1])
          t2 = as.character(p[i, 2]) == as.character(x[2])
          mycond = cond1 + cond2 
          TT = t1 + t2 
          if (TT + mycond >= z){
            return(c(as.character(p[i, 3]), as.character(x[3])))
          }

        }
      })
```

Anyone knows how can I do this? Or is this possible by any other ways? I want to repeat these lines in my code for more than this numbers.

Comment: it is probably easier when you include your input data and expected output data as no one will understand or read your loops.

Comment: to understand your question it would be nice when you can provide  some test data